# 2 asyncTask called in an activity and result generate dynamic content

Tags: android, dynamic, android-linearlayout, textview

i'm generating dynamic `TextView` in an Activity loaded just after the user is logged. I use a webservice to retrieve some data (all user names) and a `textView` is created for each one. As i have http requests, it is performed in another thread (`Asynctask`). Before items are created, i wait the query's result and return it in `"OnPostExecute"`.
I have my list of user and each item is clickable, and i want now to display some information when i click on it but i don't know how to do it.

Here is my code :

operation.java

```
public class operation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>>
{
public ArrayList<String> doLogin(AndroidHttpClient client, String userName,
        String userAccessKey) { ..}
public ArrayList<String> doQuery(AndroidHttpClient client,
        String sessionName, String query) { ...}
@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
    final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient
            .newInstance("Android");

    if (params[2] == "login") {
        ArrayList<String> sessionName = doLogin(client, params[0],
                params[1]);
        return sessionName;
    } else if (params[2] == "query") {
        return doQuery(client, params[3],
                "select accountname from Accounts;");
    }

    return null;

}
```

QueryActivityClass :

```
public class QueryActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.query);


    Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

    // Display users' name when the activity is launched
    // creating dynamic TextView items for each user
    // and allows the user to click on it to display more information.
    // It calls the function "doInBackGround" to make http requests
    // (queries) in another thread and retrieve the result to generate a
    // dynamic page
    new operation() {
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

            LinearLayout dynamicWindow = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.windowLayout);
            dynamicWindow.removeAllViewsInLayout();

            // create a dynamic LinearLayout which will contain our
            // TextViews
            LinearLayout dynamicContent = new LinearLayout(
                    QueryActivity.this);
            dynamicContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            dynamicContent.setBackgroundColor(0xFF007AAD);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            dynamicWindow.addView(dynamicContent);

            // retrieve every name returned from the query and create a
            // TextView for each one
            int nbTextView = result.size();
            TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[nbTextView];

            for (int i = 0; i < nbTextView; i++) {
                Log.i("Contenu ArrayList",
                        "item n°" + i + " = " + result.get(i));
                textViewArray[i] = new TextView(QueryActivity.this);
                textViewArray[i].setText(result.get(i));
                textViewArray[i].setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                textViewArray[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textViewArray[i].setGravity(2);
                textViewArray[i].setId(+i);
                textViewArray[i].setLeft(10 + (i * 2));
                final int test = i;

                // makes the TextView clickable
                textViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

/* HERE IS THE PART I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DOW */

                    }
                });

                // add the TextView to the linearLayout
                dynamicContent.addView(textViewArray[i],
                        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            }
        }
    }.execute(null, null, "query", sessionName);

    // When the "back" button is clicked, the activity is destroyed and the
    // previous activity on the stack is loaded 
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }

    });

}
```

}

So i want to display information in the middle of the screen when i click on a user name, but i would have to do another http request to retrieve his information. it involves that i call `doInBackground` again by making `new Operation().execute(...)` and add another case in the doInbackground function in the class operation. I'm a little bit lost, please somebody have an idea ?
PS : if you find something in my code that can be improved ... :)
Thx

Comment: ok i found another way to do it. I store all information about my clients in a DB SQLite when my page/activity is created, so that i don't have to send a HTTP request every time i click on the TextView because i already have the data